# the characteristic function of $S_N=\sum_\limits{i=1}^{n}X_i$

Tags: probability-theory

> Let $N,X_1,X_2,...$ independent random variables, $N\in\{1,2,...\}$ almost certainly and let $S_n=\sum_\limits{i=1}^{n}X_i$.
>   Suppose $P(N=n)=p_n$,$n\geqslant 1$ and let $\phi_i$ characteristic function of $X_i$ for $i\geqslant 1$. Determine the characteristic function of $S_N$ and comment the result.

$\phi(S_N)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{it S_N}dP=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{it\sum_\limits{i=1}^{N}X_i }dP=?$

Is $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{it\sum_\limits{i=1}^{N}X_i }dP=\prod_\limits{i=1}^{N}{e}^{itX_i}P_i$?

**Questions:**

What is meant on this exercise? How should I solve it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$
\begin{align}
Ee^{itS_N}
&=E\left[\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{itS_n} I(N=n)\right]\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty E\left[ e^{itS_n} I(N=n)\right]\tag{0}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty Ee^{it S_n} P(N=n)\tag{1}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\prod_{k=1}^n \varphi_{X_k}(t) P(N=n)\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
where in (1) we used the independence of the $X_i$ from $N$, in (2) we used the independence once more and in (0), the swapping of $E$ and the sums can be justified by noting that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty E|e^{itS_n} I(N=n)|\leq 1<\infty$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! And $I$ in your statement is the indicator function, right?

Comment: Yes that is correct.